# How to run methods inside a standard try catch

Tags: java

It's been a while since I have done any Java programming. And I find my self a bit stuck.

My problem is that I have a pooled db connection in tomcat. That is working nicely. But there is a lot of boiler plate required.

```
    public void init() {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {

        //SETUP 
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc");
        OracleDataSource ds = (OracleDataSource) envContext.lookup("tclsms");

        if (envContext == null) throw new Exception("Error: No Context");
        if (ds == null) throw new Exception("Error: No DataSource");
        if (ds != null) conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) throw new Exception("Error: No Connection")

        message = "Got Connection " + conn.toString() + ", ";

        //BODY 
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 'Success obtaining connection' FROM DUAL");

        if (rst.next()) message = rst.getString(1);



        //TEAR DOWN 
        rst.close();
        rst = null;
        stmt.close();
        stmt = null;
        conn.close(); // Return to connection pool
        conn = null; // Make sure we don't close it twice
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO proper error handling 
    } finally {
        // Always make sure result sets and statements are closed,
        // and the connection is returned to the pool
        if (rst != null) {
            try {
                rst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;}
            rst = null;
        }

        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;}
            stmt = null;
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;}
            conn = null;
        }
    } //END FINALLY
} //END INIT
```

So I want to do the equivalent of passing a method into init that will run in the body of the function. I know I can't do this in Java. But I'm sure there must be a nice way to do this. Or at least a best practice for this sort of thing.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you mean that you would like to have a method for setup, other for body, etc..??

Comment: Yeah sort of, more that I would like to have a standard wrapper for setup and tear down. So I do not have to copy and paste the same boilerplate every where.

Comment: You can cut down your boilerplate some by making a `Closer` object with several `close` methods each taking a different parameter: `Closeable`, `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`, etc. And otherwise, a common way to do this is to create a `TransactionExecutor` class that takes a `Runnable` style object and has an `execute` method which creates the transaction, executes the method from the Runnable style object passing in the `Connection` and/or `Statement` in as a parameter and handles cleanup when done via `try`/`finally` or some such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface IDbAction {
    public DbActionResult runAction(Connection conn);
}

class DbActionResult {

    Statement statement;
    ResultSet resultSet;

    public DbActionResult(Statement statement, ResultSet resultSet){
        this.statement = statement;
        this.resultSet = resultSet;
    }

    public void getStatement(){ return this.statement; }
    public void getResultSet(){ return this.resultSet; }
}

public void runAgainstDB(IDbAction action) {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        //SETUP 
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc");
        OracleDataSource ds = (OracleDataSource) envContext.lookup("tclsms");

        if (envContext == null) throw new Exception("Error: No Context");
        if (ds == null) throw new Exception("Error: No DataSource");
        if (ds != null) conn = ds.getConnection();
        if (conn == null) throw new Exception("Error: No Connection")

        message = "Got Connection " + conn.toString() + ", ";

        //BODY 
        DbActionResult actionResult = action.runAction(conn);

        //TEAR DOWN 

        if((rst = actionResult.getResultSet()) != null){
            rst.close();
            rst = null;
        }

        if((stmt = actionResult.getStatement()) != null){
            stmt.close();
            stmt = null;
        }

        actionResult = null;

        conn.close(); // Return to connection pool
        conn = null; // Make sure we don't close it twice
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO proper error handling 
    } finally {
        // Always make sure result sets and statements are closed,
        // and the connection is returned to the pool
        if (rst != null) {
            try {
                rst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;}
            rst = null;
        }

        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;}
            stmt = null;
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {;}
            conn = null;
        }
    } //END FINALLY
} //END
```

Use like:

```
IDbAction action = new IDbAction(){

    public DbActionResult prcoessAction(Connection conn){
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 'Success obtaining connection' FROM DUAL");

        if (rst.next()) message = rst.getString(1);

        return new DbActionResult(stmt, rst);
    }

}

runAgainstDB(action);
```

Comment: Where does the `runAgainstDB` method reside?

Comment: @tieTYT In a utility class perhaps? eg DBActionUtils.runAgainstDb(...);

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class UseDBConnectionTask extends Runnable {

    private Connection conn;

    public UseDBConnectionTask(){
        setUp();
    }

    // should probably refine this to specific exceptions
    public abstract void process() throws Exception; 

    public void run(){

        try{
            process()
            // this should catch specific exceptions
        } catch (Exception e){
            // handle
        } finally {
            tearDown();
        }
    }

    Connection getConnection(){
        return conn;
    }

    public void setUp(){
        // SETUP here
        // set the conn field
    }

    public void tearDown(){
        // TEAR DOWN here
    }
}
```

use like:

```
UseDBConnectionTask dbTransaction = new UseDBConnectionTask(){

    public void process(){
        // do processing 
        // use conn via getConnection()
        // eg
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 'Success obtaining connection' FROM DUAL");

        String message = null;
        if (rst.next()) message = rst.getString(1);
    }

}

new Thread(dbTransaction).start();
```

The advantage of extending Runnable is that you can then pass this instance into a thread pool or similar.
Just have to be careful of threading issues. It also assumes that the tear down is always the same.

Comment: I don't think this is good (as written).  You don't close the `stmt` or the `rst`.  You made the `tearDown` private so he can't overwrite the logic.  This won't compile because the process impl will throw an Exception.  These are nits, but I think when you fix these problems you'll realize you can't use this overall idea.

Comment: Yeah I think this is more of a template. Not a complete answer. I have adapted it and it's working well.

Comment: Prefer delegation to inheritance. Use an interface instead of an abstract class

Comment: @DanWalmsley No offense, but I doubt that.  Your sample code has many problems with it.  For example, it closes and creates these objects in the wrong place.  Most likely your adaptered code seems to work but will have strange issues if you run it a long period of time.

Comment: @tieTYT please elaborate, I would like avoid any strange issues.

Comment: @DanWalmsley Here's a good example of how to do it: http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/  I don't necessarily rollback, but the rest is what I usually do.

Answer (score 1):

You should **prefer delegation to inheritance**. The above can/will work but isn't well thought out.

Implementing Runnable on the primary class exposes it for abuse because the 'run()' method is public.

A second improvement is to use to **delegate your activity to an interface** (and this CAN be passed around like a function pointer whereas extending the class cannot). In addition, it makes it Spring friendly

This allows the action implementer to decide if they want multi-threaded behavior or not. You can inject composites, caching delegates, etc and the primary class is none-the-wiser. This conforms with good design practice of **separation of concerns**

```
public class MyClass {

    private Action action;

    public MyClass (Action action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void connection() {

        try{
            action.perform()
        } catch (Exception e){
            // handle
        } finally {
            tearDown();
        }
    }

    Connection getConnection(){
        return conn;
    }

    private void setUp(){
        // SETUP here
        // set the conn field
    }

    private void tearDown(){
        // TEAR DOWN here
    }

}
```

Comment: All very good points. I have added an alternative answer that addresses these. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16576681/417906.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Todo(Context initContext, Context envContext, OracleDataSource ds){

            if (envContext == null) throw new Exception("Error: No Context");
            if (ds == null) throw new Exception("Error: No DataSource");
            if (ds != null) conn = ds.getConnection();
            if (conn == null) throw new Exception("Error: No Connection")

            message = "Got Connection " + conn.toString() + ", ";

            //BODY 
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 'Success obtaining connection' FROM DUAL");

            if (rst.next()) message = rst.getString(1);



            //TEAR DOWN 
            rst.close();
            rst = null;
            stmt.close();
            stmt = null;
            conn.close(); // Return to connection pool
            conn = null; // Make sure we don't close it twice
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //TODO proper error handling 
        } finally {
            // Always make sure result sets and statements are closed,
            // and the connection is returned to the pool
            if (rst != null) {
                try {
                    rst.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {;}
                rst = null;
            }

            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {;}
                stmt = null;
            }

            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {;}
                conn = null;
            }
        } //END FINALLY
}
```

Then call it from your Init like this `this. Todo(initContext,envContext , ds`)